# Flutter: The side property of OutlineButton seems to have no effect

Tags: flutter, button, dart

Produces an `OutlineButton` with a white border:

```
OutlineButton(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    side: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.purple
    )
  ),
)
```

Produces a `FlatButton` with a purple border:

```
FlatButton(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    side: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.purple
    )
  ),
)
```

Part of the documentation for `OutlineButton`:

> borderSide → BorderSide
>   Defines the color of the border when the button is enabled but not pressed, and the border outline's width and style in general. [...]
>   final

Comment: For me, after I handle `onPressed` , then the border color starts to appear, of course, you need `borderSize` and `shape`

Comment: @onmyway133 Hey, you can see the official answer below. I confused the side and the borderside property back then. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`OutlineButton` has a property named `borderSide` you can use it directly :

```
        OutlineButton(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.purple
            ),
        )
```

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/OutlineButton/borderSide.html

Comment: That was ridiculous that I confused them, lol. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

With **Flutter 2.0** `OutlineButton` is deprecated and you should use `OutlinedButton` instead.

**Note:** If you use `shape` property and want to give color to your border, then you should place `side` property in two places in order to have an effect. Like this:

```
  OutlinedButton(
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(14)),
               side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0), // HERE
          ),
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0)), // AND HERE
     onPressed: () {},
     child: Text(
       'Details',
       style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          color: Colors.black,
     ),
   ),
 ),
```

Comment: I was able to define side in just the styleFrom, and left it null in the RoundedRectangleBorder.

Answer (score 0):

handle `onPressed:(){}` like this.
the color will appear.
later You can change the function in onPressed.
cheers...